# how to produce a nested list from two lists in python

Tags: python, list, tuples, nested-lists

I am a newbie in python,
I have two lists:

```
l1 = ['a','b','c','d']
l2 = ['new']
```

i want to get new list like this

```
l3 = [('a','new'),('b','new'),('c','new'),('d','new')]
```

What is the best way to combine the two lists?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> l1 = ['a','b','c','d']
>>> l2 = ['new']
>>> list(product(l1,l2))
[('a', 'new'), ('b', 'new'), ('c', 'new'), ('d', 'new')]
```

Answer (score 5):

If `l2` always just has the one element there is no need to overcomplicate things

```
l3 = [(x, l2[0]) for x in l1]
```

Comment: This is also useful answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

See the [itertools docs](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product).

In particular, use product for a Cartesian product:

```
from itertools import product:
l1 = ['a','b','c','d']
l2 = ['new']
# Cast to list for l3 to be a list since product returns a generator
l3 = list(product(l1, l2))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> from itertools import repeat
>>> l1 = ['a','b','c','d']
>>> l2 = ['new']
>>> zip(l1,repeat(*l2))
[('a', 'new'), ('b', 'new'), ('c', 'new'), ('d', 'new')]
```

Comment: I think my other solution is better :D

Comment: I would use `repeat` rather than `cycle`.

Comment: but `repeat` would return the whole list

Comment: nvm i can just unpack it, i will change it to `repeat`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply take use of list comprehension without any functions:

l3 = [(x, y) for x in l1 for y in l2]