# How to apply itertools.product to a nested list in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, nested-lists

Let say I have a nested list of string

```
lst = [['a'], ['b', 'c'], ['d', ['e', 'f']]]
```

I want to generate all possible combination from the nested list to something like this:

```
new_lst = [['a', 'b', 'd'],
           ['a', 'b', 'e', 'f'],
           ['a', 'c', 'd'],
           ['a', 'c', 'e', 'f']]
```

I have found some question that may related to my question. 
[how to produce a nested list from two lists in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10394358/how-to-produce-a-nested-list-from-two-lists-in-python)
However, my question is more complicated issue.

Comment: I would flatten the list and then use sets. `itertools` probably has a method that does this automatically.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8371887/making-all-possible-combinations-of-a-list-in-python

Comment: @MidhunMohan in that question they are taking combinations from a simple list while OP is asking product of his particular nested list

Comment: @JonKiparsky, I don't believe you *fixed* the title but diluted it.  I believe the correct title would be more like, "How to apply itertools.product to a nested list in Python".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's what will do the trick -

```
import itertools
lst = [['a'], ['b', 'c'], ['d', ['e', 'f']]]
outp = list(itertools.product(*lst))
out = []
for i in outp:
    temp = []
    for j in i:
        if isinstance(j, list):
            for k in j:
                temp.append(k)
        else:
            temp.append(j)
    out.append(temp)
print(out)
```

Start off by forming the output materials using `itertools.product` and then simply formatting it in a way that the nested lists are flattened out.

Output

```
[['a', 'b', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'e', 'f'], ['a', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'c', 'e', 'f']]
```

Comment: Good answer .try to avoid that `print(here)` statement

Comment: hmm strange why this was down voted, its a perfectly working solution.

Comment: @VikasDamodar took care of it. Thanks!

Comment: @RoadRunner Wondering the same :-)

Answer (score 4):

Similar to @VivekKalyanarangan but with a proper flattener:

```
>>> def flatten(nl):
...     for e in nl:
...         if isinstance(e, str):
...             yield e
...             continue
...         try:
...             yield from flatten(e)
...         except TypeError:
...             yield e
... 

>>> lst = [['a'], ['b', 'c'], ['d', ['e', 'f']]]
>>> 
>>> list(map(list, map(flatten, itertools.product(*lst))))
[['a', 'b', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'e', 'f'], ['a', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'c', 'e', 'f']]
```

Comment: If I change the data to be `lst = [[1], [2, 3], [4, [5, 6]]]`, this solution still works.  So what is the `isinstance(e, str)` really doing for you?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `chain.from_iterable()` to flattern results:

```
from itertools import product, chain

lst = [['a'], ['b', 'c'], ['d', ['e', 'f']]]

[list(chain.from_iterable(i)) for i in product(*lst)]
# [['a', 'b', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'e', 'f'], ['a', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'c', 'e', 'f']]
```

Answer (score -1):

Another way by using list comprehension

```
>>> ls = [['a'], ['b', 'c'], ['d', ['e', 'f']]]
>>> res = ['']
>>> for elem in ls:
...     res = [list(j) + list(e) for j in res for e in elem]
... 
>>> res
[['a', 'b', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'e', 'f'], ['a', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'c', 'e', 'f']]
```

Answer (score -2):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
from itertools import permutations
lst = [['a'], ['b', 'c'], ['d', ['e', 'f']]]
list(permutations(lst))
```

Otherwise, give this a try:

```
lst = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']
list(permutations(lst))   ##will return all possible combos
```